# Add menu items on WordPress is disabled

Tags: wordpress, elementor

So im about to add page for my menu on WordPress but somehow the menu on the left is disabled. How can i solve this problem? Thanks :)
[heres the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fLKW.png)

Comment: first create a menu and add items

Answer (score 0):

Just write your menu name in "Menu Name" field and click on "Create Menu" button. After that you can able to add pages to your menu. :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).